# Design public vector that any class function can access and print contents in main

Tags: c++, arrays, class, vector

I am fairly new to C++ and am trying to write a little program where a string from a member function is stored into a public vector array.

I have written two functions where each stores a message into this vector, however when attempting to output the contents in main, nothing is printed.

classTest.h:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Test
{
public:
    //std::vector<std::string> buffer
    std::vector<std::string> buffer;

    void msg1();
    void msg2();
};
```

classTest.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "classTest.h"

void Test::msg1()
{
    Test test;
    std::string message = "HELLO";
    test.buffer.push_back(message);
}

void Test::msg2()
{
    Test test;
    std::string message = "WORLD";
    test.buffer.push_back(message);

}

int main()
{
    Test *test = new Test;

    test->msg1();
    test->msg2();
    std::cout << test->buffer.size() << std::endl;
    //std::cout << test->buffer.at(1) << std::endl;
    //std::cout << test->buffer.at(2) << std::endl;

    return 1;
}
```

Size output is 0, and if I attempt `test->buffer.at(0)` I get an out of range error.

All I want to do is have the `msg1` and `msg2` functions write into the public buffer and have it output in console in main. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test` instance in methods `msg1()` and `msg2()` are local to those methods only and go out-of-scope when those methods exit.

So, you would want to do this:

```
buffer.push_back( message );
```

In addition, an [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a zero-based container so the first element would be `at(0)` and so on.

Another thing is that you're leaking memory. You allocate memory using `new` operator but do not `delete` it after use. So, you need to take care of that also. Better yet, use a smart pointer e.g. [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) with [std::make_unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) for automatic memory management.

Here's a complete working example ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/dXVePG)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Test
{
public:
    std::vector<std::string> buffer;

    void msg1();
    void msg2();
};

void Test::msg1()
{
    std::string message = "HELLO";
    buffer.push_back(message);
}

void Test::msg2()
{
    std::string message = "WORLD";
    buffer.push_back(message);
}

int main()
{
    Test *test = new Test;  // memory allocation

    test->msg1();
    test->msg2();
    std::cout << test->buffer.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << test->buffer.at(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << test->buffer.at(1) << std::endl;

    delete test;            // memory deallocation
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2    
HELLO    
WORLD
```

A relevant thread you might want to read: [C++: "std::endl" vs "\n"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)

Answer (score 0):

You need to read a good book on C++, it appears.

Your member functions operate on a local variable named `test` which goes away when the functions end.

Here's the updated ones which hopefully will behave correctly.

```
void Test::msg1()
{
    std::string message = "HELLO";
    buffer.push_back(message);
}

void Test::msg2()
{
    std::string message = "WORLD";
    buffer.push_back(message);
}
```

Comment: there's a mistake i'll never be making again. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that constructer to your class, inside your class, and that just wouldn't work. Instead you go directly to your class.

```
void Test::msg1()
{
    std::string message = "HELLO";
    Test::buffer.push_back(message);
}

void Test::msg2()
{
    std::string message = "WORLD";
    Test::buffer.push_back(message);
}
```